# How do I change the rails environment an app I just deployed to production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I just deployed a dummy rails 3.1.0.rc6 app to a rackspace server. Two things

First when i ssh in the run

```
rails c
Sprockets::Environment#static_root is deprecated
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0.rc6)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.env
=> "development"
```

Does this mean its in development environment and if so how do i change to production and second in the log folder i have

```
ls log
development.log  passenger.3000.log  production.log
```

but they are all blank for some reason

here is my [url](http://active.posnation.net/) and it appears that something is wrong but no logs indicate the problem

```
<VirtualHost 50.57.119.54:80>
      ServerAdmin test@tes.com
      ServerName active.posnation.net
      # ServerAlias
      DocumentRoot /var/www/active.posnation.net/public
      ErrorLog /var/www/active.posnation.net/logs/error.log

      RailsEnv production
        <Directory "/var/www/active.posnation.net/public">
          Order allow,deny
          Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run `rails c`, it will default to development mode. This does not mean your actual live app is running in development mode. If you're using Passenger, it will default to run your app in production mode unless you tell it otherwise.

To get the console to run in development mode, call `rails c development` instead.

As far as the log files are concerned, have you checked the permissions on the files to make sure Passenger can write to them (and to make sure you can then read them)?

Comment: adding my vhost file to my question so you can see

Comment: should i remove the       ErrorLog /var/www/active.posnation.net/logs/error.log
from my vhost then

Comment: lastly how can i tell if passenger can write to them ...they are root/root

Comment: If the files are owned by root, and don't have world writeable permissions, then apache won't be able to write to them (assuming that apache isn't running as root). You can either change the ownership to the user that apache runs as, or you can make them world writeable.

Comment: how coe when i run rake db:create it only create the development and test db and not production

Comment: i see the issue its rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production